# Why is redis shutting down?

Tags: ubuntu, redis, zmalloc

No sooner I make a query to my redis server it closes throwing an error:

```
zmalloc: Out of memory trying to allocate 41 bytes
```

**About my machine:**

```
Tasks:  18 total,   1 running,  17 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3670016k total,   521580k used,  3148436k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   485044k cached
```

What is this error and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you attach the output of your Redis' INFO?

Comment: @ItamarHaber: And how to do that?

Comment: Use redis-cli, i.e.: `redis-cli INFO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to build a bit 32-bit binary. It can address no more than 2GB of
memory. You can try building a 64-bit binary of Redis yourself and try again if it solves the issue for you.Try to check the ulimit settings for your machine and increase the same. A similar thread for same :https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/06VTpFctoFc